# How to do the opposite of string::copy C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

How to copy std::string to specific index in char array in C++ ?

example :

```
    std::string str = "aaaabbb";
    unsigned char arr[3];
    str.copyToFunction(arr,4,3);
```

result :

```
    arr value should be = "bbb".
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Does it works with std::array ? or there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without bounds checking (which you probably need to do first):

```
std::copy(str.begin() + 4, str.end(), arr);
```

Note there is no null termination, which you probably want to add:

```
auto end = std::copy(str.begin() + 4, str.end(), arr);
*end++ = '\0';
```

Of course `arr` must now have length 4 at least.

Comment: Does std::copy works with std::array or there is another way ?

Comment: @AhmedTajElsir: yes it works.  You'd say `arr.begin()` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

std::copy(str.begin() + 4, str.begin() + 4 + 3, arr);

[std::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) documentation

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
std::string str = "aaaabbb";
std::vector<char> myvector (7);
std::copy ( str, str+7, myvector.begin()+4, myvector.end() );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the array indeed keep string literal "bbb" then you have to declare the array like

```
    unsigned char arr[4];
```

Otherwise if you do not need to append the array with the terminating zero then the array can be declared as you did.

You can use for example a standard C function declared in header `<cstring>`.

```
#include <cstring>

//...


memcpy( arr, str.c_str() + 4, 3 );
```

Or you can use standard algorithm `std::copy` declared in header `<algorithm>`

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::copy( str.begin() + 4, str.begin() + 7, arr );
```

Or you can rewrite the same using standard function `std::next` declared in header `<iterator>`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>    
//...

std::copy( std::next( str.begin(), 4 ), std::next( str.begin(), 7 ), arr );
```

If you need that the array would contain a string then as I said early you have to append zero

```
    unsigned char arr[4];

    // using some method of copying

    arr[3] = '\0;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)? Very good at chopping up strings

Comment: I think it returns std::string not char [] , Am I right ?

Comment: Can use `c_str()` afterwards - but why have char arrays?